# Looping objects to check if specific property exists, is there a nicer way maybe using underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects and would like to check if a specific key/value exists, I'm currently using a for..in loop but was wondering if there is shorter/better way to do this?

**JS**

```
var models = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "James"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ken"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Jason"
  }
];

function checkNameExists(name) {
    for( var model in models ) {
        if (models[model].name === name) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

var nameExists = checkNameExists("Ken");

if(nameExists) {
    console.log('Name exists');
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/c21opmj8/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use underscore's **some** function :

```
var nameExists = _.some(models, function (elem) {
            return elem.name == "Jason"
})
```

or in a shorter version as Ahmad Mageed suggested :

```
var useFound = _.some(models,{ 'name': 'Jasonn' });
```

Here is a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c21opmj8/2/

Comment: With LoDash this can be shorter: `_.some(models, 'name', 'Jason')`. Another option for both LoDash and Underscore: `_.some(models, { 'name': 'Jason' })`

Answer (score 2):

In plain vanilla, you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on any array

```
function checkNameExists(name) {
    return models.some(function(e){return e.name===name;});
}
```

(can be used without the function as well since you don't need the loop)

If [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) get wide spread support, readability will be better ;) Then you could use `models.some(e => e.name===name)`

Answer (score 1):

Without depending on external libraries, `Array.filter()` does the job:

```
models.filter( (x) => x.name==="Jason" )
```

`Array.find()` finds first occurrence and stops, hence it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with underscore

```
console.clear();

var models = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "James"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ken"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Jason"
  }
];

var tab_name = _.map(models, function(x){return x.name});
var name_exists = _.contains( tab_name , 'Ken')

if( name_exists ) {
    console.log('Name exists');
}
```